# Provide the short URL link to questions and answers on the mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

The mobile site is missing the buttons that provide the permalinks to a question and its answers; the buttons to share a question via Facebook and Twitter are also omitted.

The value in adding the "link" button to the mobile site are two-fold:

- Although mobile browsers make it easy to copy the current URL, but this only works for the question, not a specific answer, which requires switching to the full site view.
- The link in the browser is probably longer (bad for Twitter) and doesn't embed the user number (for badge purposes).

There's space next to the edit link in the current mobile layout and I would be surprised if sharing Q&As via links was not a major use case of Stack Exchange sites on mobile devices.

Comment: This question could be asked for every feature on the full site that's missing from the mobile site. The answer is, "to save space/simplify".

Comment: Well sure, but asking the question and gauging the responses is one source of feedback for the developers to know if they've cut the right things. One thing mobile devices are good for is linking to social networks and the ability to copy and paste a link is a robust way to interface between apps. So the question is really asking for someone to justify this decision on specific grounds.

Comment: If that's what your question is meant for, I'm tempted to -1 vote it. I would recommend instead making the feature request.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Isn't it a feature request now? All I have to do is add the tag right? Do you recommend I re-word the question to be more of a statement requesting that the link link be added to the mobile page? I don't use MSO much, so any help you can offer on conventions, etc. would be appreciated.

Comment: It is *always* best to be clear and concise. Ask/state exactly what you really want, and nothing else. Many people do, in fact, want to know "why", and so ask that. In your comment, you even said "So the question is really asking for someone to justify this decision". In my opinion, that is rarely productive.

Comment: +1: this is exactly what I was going to ask this evening.  True, this _could_ be said of every feature on the full site, but having browsed SO on my phone a lot lately, the lack of this particular feature stands out to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is now available.

Screenshot from iPhone:

> [image]