# How can I get a link for a specific answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

How can I get a link for a specific answer on Stack Overflow? Like the url of the answer. Is there a place to do that or a specific way? And if you think there's a share button, I don't see one anywhere?

Comment: There's a "share" link under every answer.

Comment: @jonsca Not for me there isn't.

Comment: @slhck Thanks.  I figured it needed one's userID for the referral, but you are correct.

Comment: @LightningBoltϟ - are you on the mobile site? It would seem that the share link is only there on the full site. There is a feature request here: [Provide the short URL link to questions and answers on the mobile site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117638/provide-the-short-url-link-to-questions-and-answers-on-the-mobile-site)

Comment: I searched several times for this answer, and started to ask this exact question. ( so up-voted the question for the title itself ) because the duplicate answer's title sucks. ( the answer I was looking for was in the duplicate question tho http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45598/246836

Answer (score 0):

O now I remembered. You can search the question name and is:answer. So for example:

```
Array match is:answer
```

Comment: ^^^^ See the share link right here?

Comment: @jonsca I don't see it!